# Pine Script Beginner - Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope

Tags: plot, scope, pine-script

I tried the following code in my script, but it doesn't work, becuase of error: Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope.

```
for i = 0 to counter_buy
    plotshape(high + counter_buy, style = shape.circle, location=location.absolute, color = color.green, size = size.auto)
```

What I'm trying to do:
There is a counter in my script (counter_buy) I want to draw a circle for each value of "1" above the current bar. So if the counter is "3" I want to draw 3 circles above the current bar. Each circle above the other, like this example:

```
 o
 o
 o
BAR
```

Is there a way to archive this?
Thanks, Mag

Answer (score -2, accepted):

thanks for your response. My solution were counters in my script that gets higher or lower at specific situations, like crossovers. Then I plot arrows above or below the current bar, with values of my counters.

```
plotarrow(counter1, colorup=color.green, colordown=color.red,  transp=30, maxheight=50)
plotarrow(counter2, colorup=color.blue,  colordown=color.blue, transp=30, maxheight=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use plot statements in `for` loops or any other local block in a script. There are 2 ways to go about this, depending on your requirements: either with multiple `plotshape()` calls or with labels.

1. Is it important that you see those circles on ALL the dataset's bars where they should appear or are you OK with only the last ~50 occurrences showing?
2. What's the max value for `counter_buy`?

Comment: Can you please write down with example? that would help us